# Reverse Integer leetcode: Why does overflow occur only if 7 or greater is added to INT_MAX?

Tags: java

I have the solution provided by Leetcode and the part that confuses me is the fact that adding 7 (or a lower value) to Integer.MAX_VALUE or adding -8 (or a lower value) to Integer.MIN_VALUE does not result in overflow or underflow respectively.

My logic is that if you have Integer.MAX_VALUE, adding 1 will cause overflow. And if you have Integer.MIN_VALUE, subtracting 1 will cause underflow. Where is my understanding of overflow and underflow wrong?

```
class Solution {
    public int reverse(int x) {
        int rev = 0;
        while (x != 0) {
            int pop = x % 10;
            x /= 10;
            if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev ==     Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
            if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
            rev = rev * 10 + pop;
        }
        return rev;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, normally adding 1 to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will result in overflow, as will subtracting 1 from `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.  But that is not what is happening here.

This code is performing integer division by `10`, which truncates any decimal portion.  When dividing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`2147483647`) by 10, the code anticipates multiplying by 10 and adding the next digit.  That quotient is `214748364`, and multiplying by `10` is `2147483640`, with the possibility of adding another 7 without overflowing.  Similarly on the negative side, dividing `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (`-2147483648`) by 10 yields `-214748364`, multiplying by 10 yields `-2147483640`, with the possibility of adding another `-8` without overflowing.

This code takes into account the last digit of the extremes of the range of `Integer` values and carefully avoids overflow.

Answer (score 5):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is **`2147483647`**

That means: `Integer.MAX_VALUE/10` is `214748364`

And you're about to do: `rev = rev * 10 + pop`

So if `rev > 214748364`, then `rev * 10` will cause overflow.

Or if `rev == 214748364`, then `rev * 10` is `2147483640`, and `rev * 10 + pop` will cause overflow if `pop > 7`.